# I need the install path to C++ in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, ide, g++

I am trying to link IntelliJ to C++ in Ubuntu and I cannot find the install path to the g++ compiler.  I know its there because I've installed it, I just can't find it.  Thanks for the help.  I'm working with IntelliJ 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command

`which g++`

it should show you the full path of your g++ command